# How can I apply CSS span to a concatenated string with NO line breaks?

Tags: javascript, string

I have the following code (in a Rocket Themed Joomla site) and I can't seem to get the Javascript to remove the newline when I add the last  tag. Here is the script:

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
var d = new Date();
var date = d.getDate();
var day = d.getDay();

function schoolDay5(){
//weekNo = Math.ceil(date/7); //See bottom of the page to see how it works
if (date%2 == 0)
return 2;
else
return 1;
}
window.onload=function(){
var str= "<span class='promo1 ribbon'>" + "Welcome to Stephen Leacock it is day " + schoolDay5()+ "<span>";
document.getElementById('notice').innerHTML=str;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="notice"></div>
</body>
```

When I run this I get a new line on the last  tag.  How can I just have this script spit out a single line?

Here is the page showing the result:[How it looks now](http://j25.stephenleacock.ca/)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you've got that span element set to `display: block;`. And it contains a span also set to `display: block;`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a line break because the empty `<span></span>` that shows the graphic (to the right of the title) (.ribbon span) has a CSS style of `display:block`. This causes it to show on it's own line.

To fix this, remove `display:block` and add `float:right`.

```
.ribbon span {background-repeat:no-repeat; padding-right:100px; background-position:100% -205px; min-height:45px; float:right;}
```